# Unable to connect to Google Play billing

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I am trying to simple connect to Google play billing & access details such as the title & the pricing but I've been unable to do so.

**What I've done so far (step-by-step):**

(Added the IAP details on Google play console as well as published the app)

1. Added the Billing permission in the Manifest file -> `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`
2. Added the Billing library (v.4.0) ->  `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'`
3. Initialized the BillingClient in MainActivity & on trying to connect to it, I get no response from the **onBillingSetupFinished** callback method

   ```
   private void initializeBillingClient(Context context) {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(this)
            .build();

    connectToGooglePlayBilling(context);
   }


   private void connectToGooglePlayBilling(Context context) {
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            connectToGooglePlayBilling(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "connected to google play billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                //I should then fetch & display premium content details
            }
        }
    });
   }
   ```

**Weird enough** I noticed that when I enable the Battery Saving Mode (I'm using a Samsung device) the `onBillingSetupFinished` method gets called as the toast is shown.

What am I doing incorrect & also if anyone can explain why enabling Battery save mode suddenly makes it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `onBillingSetupFinished` is called in UI thread.
Try to use `runOnUiThread` to show the message:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> 
                Toast.makeText(context, "connected to google play billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```